# Exporting multiple layers to single dxf file using Grass GIS?

Tags: grass-gis, export, dxf

I'm very new to Grass GIS.

I need to export multiple vector layers into a single dxf file (required in order to import into another application).

However, I can't see a way of selecting more than one layer at the same time for export to a single dxf.

Is this actually possible in Grass GIS?

Answer (score 1):

Patch (merge) the two vector maps together (I'm using *roadsmajor* and *streams* from the North Carolina sample dataset for GRASS GIS):

```
v.patch input=roadsmajor,streams output=roads_and_streams
```

Export using GDAL/OGR:

```
v.out.ogr input=roads_and_streams format=DXF output=roads_and_streams1.dxf
```

Alternatively, export using specialized module:

```
v.out.dxf i=roads_and_streams o=roads_and_streams2.dxf
```

Just for checking the resulting geometries, I imported both files back to GRASS GIS using always the other complimentary tool (`v.in.dxf` for `v.out.ogr` output and `v.in.ogr` for `v.out.dxf` output).

To do this in GUI, just use the (Command) *Console* tab, paste the name of the module (e.g. `v.patch`), press Enter, and fill the dialog.